# Can I get information about AWS Lambda request IDs, e.g. the trigger?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

In my logs I find

```
START RequestId: 123a1a12-1234-1234-1234-123456789012 Version: $LATEST
```

for every invocation of AWS lambda. Is it possible to get more information about a request, e.g. what triggered it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda function has two parameters: Event and [context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html).

A normal invocation looks like this:

```
{
    "event": {
        "version": "0",
        "id": "abcdefgh-1234-5678-1234-abcdefghijkl",
        "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
        "source": "aws.events",
        "account": "123456789012",
        "time": "2018-01-01T12:00:00Z",
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "resources": [
            "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:123456788901:rule/foo"
        ],
        "detail": {}
    },
    "context": "<__main__.LambdaContext object at 0x123456ax1234>"
}
```

The test invocation has the elements you get.

Comment: My event invocations (calling lambda functions from appsync) do not have the `id` field. However, my context does have an `aws_request_id` field, which is that UUID that is displayed in the logs. re: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html

Comment: Hi @Martin Thoma, I have to get a message-id and request-id when we use SNS  in lambda. how to verify message is send or not by using message and request-id

Answer (score 20):

You can get the **request id** and other information **from the context object**.

> When Lambda runs your function, it passes a context object to the handler. This object provides methods and properties that provide information about the invocation, function, and execution environment.
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html

You can get further information from the **process.env** variable.

I wrote a short lambda function (node.js) which logs these information to the console and ends up in aws cloud watch

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('context:', JSON.stringify(context));
    console.log('process.env:', JSON.stringify(process.env));

    return {statusCode: 200, body: 'Hello World'};
};
```

Log output:

```
START RequestId: 6f3c103e-f0a5-4982-934c-dabedda0065e Version: $LATEST
context:
{
    "callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop": true,
    "functionVersion": "$LATEST",
    "functionName": "my_lambda_function_name",
    "memoryLimitInMB": "128",
    "logGroupName": "/aws/lambda/my_lambda_function_name",
    "logStreamName": "2020/10/01/[$LATEST]8adb13668eed4ac8b3e7f8d796fe4d49",
    "invokedFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:636121343751:function:my_lambda_function_name",
    "awsRequestId": "6f3c103e-f0a5-4982-934c-dabedda0065e"
}
process.env:
{
    "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION": "$LATEST",
    "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN": "IZZ3eS6vFF...",
    "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib",
    "LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT": "/var/task",
    "AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME": "/aws/lambda/my_lambda_function_name",
    "AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API": "127.0.0.1:9001",
    "AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME": "2020/10/01/[$LATEST]8adb13668eed4ac8b3e7f8d796fe4d49",
    "AWS_EXECUTION_ENV": "AWS_Lambda_nodejs12.x",
    "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME": "my_lambda_function_name",
    "AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS": "169.254.79.2:2000",
    "PATH": "/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin",
    "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": "us-east-1",
    "PWD": "/var/task",
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "5nQrpKhBwF...",
    "LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR": "/var/runtime",
    "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8",
    "NODE_PATH": "/opt/nodejs/node12/node_modules:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:/var/runtime/node_modules:/var/runtime:/var/task",
    "AWS_REGION": "us-east-1",
    "TZ": ":UTC",
    "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "ASIAZNANWY3473BTADSB",
    "SHLVL": "0",
    "_AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS": "169.254.79.2",
    "_AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_PORT": "2000",
    "AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING": "LOG_ERROR",
    "_HANDLER": "index.handler",
    "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_MEMORY_SIZE": "128",
    "_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID": "Root=1-6f75f4e5-5801599f17fd63e74ecd0833;Parent=73fb93812cdbf83f;Sampled=0"
}
END RequestId: 6f3c103e-f0a5-4982-934c-dabedda0065e
REPORT RequestId: 6f3c103e-f0a5-4982-934c-dabedda0065e
Duration: 21.71 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms 
Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 64 MB  Init Duration: 132.35 ms
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to get this information from your lambda function context .

```
    RequestId=context.aws_request_id
```

You will get following result
RequestId- "00cfaafe-5018-4be0-9668-b98daf5a7312" Version: $LATEST

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand what you mean by `what triggered it`? If it's connected to the API Gateway, then requests are proxied through the Gateway to your Lambda. In that case the Gateway triggered it, even though it was a proxied request.

Additionally and you can augment your Gateway to pass additional request info to your Lambda. [See how](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/)

And also, to attach the request details to the RequestID you're seeing, you can check the `context.awsRequestId`.

I'd assume you want to do some form of log monitoring, in which case I think you can bundle up these request information(headers, query, params, body) and send to your log aggregator along with the awsRequestId.
Let me know if that helps

[Further reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html)

Comment: I want to know it it was triggered by me clicking on "test" or by something else.

Comment: in that case I think my response should be able to answer that. I mean you can log the requestId and crosscheck that with what you have in the cloudwatch logs, unless you want to augment what's in Cloudwatch. Moreover, clicking on "test" is a delibrate action, so you can just easily check the logged requestID and compare with the records on Cloudwatch

Comment: Just don't click "Test" at all. That's method of testing is very easily misunderstood. (Not your fault. It's AWS' bad UI/UX).

Comment: When invoked from API Gateway, the context object contains a requestId property that is the API Gateway request ID. This does not match the Lambda request ID that Lambda writes to the CloudWatch logs. API Gateway returns its own request ID in the response headers, but this is not useable to find the corresponding Lambda logs for that request. I would like to return the Lambda request ID in the response headers from my application.